# Javascript won't load in my Handlebars rendered site

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

So I've got a site that is rendered with Handlebars, and built out using Express, MongoDB and Mongoose. The site renders and my data from the DB will populate, but I cannot get my main app.js file to run. I've had it in the public folder, which is served up in my server file as the static location, but while it registers in the network tab, it won't actually run any of it's logic. I've tried a bunch of stuff, and literally zero change.

The main script call has largely been located in my template file, but I've tried a number of variations, all with the same result. I've read multiple docs on handlebars and such, and I've even had other projects I've done where the js file loads fine. I have NO idea what is missing, and I've had several folks try to help me and be stumped. Help Stack Overflow, you're my only hope!!!

FYI, here is my layout page for the hbs stuff, and my app.js file. It is located in public/assets folders. I'm at a loss.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".scrape-new", function(request, response) {
        console.log
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/scrape"
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            response.send("data scraped");
            response.redirect("/");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            throw error;
        })
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg" href="/assets/images/newspaper-solid.svg">
    <title>Onion Scraper</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{{body}}}
    <script src="/assets/app.js" type="javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To clarify: when you say app.js registers in the network tab, that means it actually downloads successfully? You don't get a 404 that the script `src` is wrong?

Comment: Yes. I get a status 200 or a status 304. It is there, and I know it is being seen by the browser? I'm not sure. It exists, and is linked but won't actually run any code. Like NONE. I even just dropped console logs at the top and nada.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so a another person found the answer. It was very weird. I got a chance to sit down and take a look. If you remove the “type” attribute from your script tag, everything loads normally. I have seen this before, but I don’t know what causes it. I’m going to research and see if I can provide some insights. 10:13 Aha! It turns out, if your javascript file is provided with a header of any type other than javascript when you specify the type, the browser will fail to load it. Express apparently loads JS files as type “script” which means the specified type (javascript) doesn’t match.
Old code: 
`<script src="/assets/app.js" type="javascript"></script>` 
to this: `<script src="/assets/app.js"></script> That suddenly fixed it`